# Running Robotium Cases in separate batches via Ant

Tags: java, android, ant, robotium, gui-testing

Basically, what I want to achieve is [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226026/how-to-run-all-junit-tests-in-a-category-suite-with-ant) but using Robotium in Ant. I want to test my packages (suites?) individually using an Ant command.

The reason for this is because the complexity of the application is so large that it encounters problems when I run everything at once, usually [terminating midway due to a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android) as Robotium plows through the cases, and [how some cases affect future cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851351/robotium-in-the-suite-of-tests-each-next-test-is-affected-by-the-previous-test) due to a change in state somewhere in the application.

Everything works perfectly when running just the current package or running each case individually though (using my IDE), so I want to know how this is achieved through Ant instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the problem myself. It's actually pretty simple as I've mimicked the behavior of ant test.

The idea is that whenever `ant test` is run, it simply invokes the `adb shell` command and triggers the instrumentation test runner `am instrument`, along with other parameters. The parameters can be customized to define which classes or packages would be tested.

The solution is to define a `target` on your `custom_rules.xml` (I use `macrodef` so I can reuse this for other targets) which performs this.

```
    <macrodef name="test-class">
    <attribute name="class"/>

    <sequential>
        <echo level="info">Running tests for @{class}</echo>
        <exec executable="${adb}" failonerror="false">
            <arg line="${adb.device.arg}"/>
            <arg value="shell"/>
            <arg value="am"/>
            <arg value="instrument"/>
            <arg value="-w"/>
            <arg value="-e"/>
            <arg value="class"/>
            <arg value="@{class}"/>
            <arg value="com.example.application/${test.runner}"/>
        </exec>
    </sequential>

</macrodef>
```

So if you want an Ant command such as test-example that tests the .tests.ExampleTest test cases, you can define it as such:

```
<target name="test-example">
     <test-class class="com.example.application.tests.ExampleTest />
</target>
```

And then run it as

```
ant clean debug install test-example
```

or just

```
ant test-example
```

Oh and this isn't Robotium-exclusive as Robotium actually builds on the existing test framework Android provides.